# Closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^n \, q^{k(n-k)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Is there a closed form of the finite sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \, q^{k(n-k)}$? Is there anything interesting to say about this? It appears naturally in a calculation of mine, and I don't know what to do with it, although it looks quite nice.

Comment: This is the same as calculating $\sum_{k=0}^m x^{k^2}$, which does not have a nice closed form in terms of $m$ and $x$.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty equivalent
to a standard theta function.

$\begin{array}\\
s_n(q)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \, q^{k(n-k)}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}q^{k(n-k)}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \, q^{kn-k^2}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \, q^{1/4-1/4+kn-k^2}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \, q^{1/4-(k-n/2)^2}\\
&=1+q^{1/4}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \, q^{-(k-n/2)^2}\\
s_{2n}(q)
&=1+q^{1/4}\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1} \, q^{-(k-n)^2}\\
&=1+q^{1/4}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}q^{-(k-n)^2}+1+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n-1}q^{-(k-n)^2}\right)\\
&=1+q^{1/4}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}q^{-k^2}+1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}q^{-(k)^2}\right)\\
&=1+q^{1/4}\left(1+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}q^{-k^2}\right)\\
s_{2n+1}(q)
&=1+q^{1/4}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \, q^{-(k-n)^2}\\
&=1+q^{1/4}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}q^{-(k-n)^2}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}q^{-(k-n)^2}\right)\\
&=1+q^{1/4}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}q^{-k^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}q^{-k^2}\right)\\
&=1+q^{1/4}\left(1+q^{-n^2}+2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}q^{-k^2}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I guess you meant $n^2/4$ instead of $1/4$.